# Saving graphs to .html using mpld3

Tags: python, flask, seaborn, mpld3

I am trying to show a graph using seaborn and mpld3 but in a .html file. When I use the command `mpld3.show()`, a new window pops and the graph is shown in a local webserver created (like the documentation describes). However, when trying to save it in a .html file, the graph comes empty but I can see some icons like move and zoom avaliable....

**With `mpld3.show()`**

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.barplot(x=df.index.tolist(), y=df['Salário'])
mpld3.show()
```

Graph how its supposed to be:

[image]

**Trying to save to .html file using `save_html()`:**

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.barplot(x=df.index.tolist(), y=df['Salário'])
fig = plt.figure()
mpld3.save_html(fig, "./templates/graph_exp.html")
```

Bugged graph with working icons
[image]

Can someone help me make this graph appear normal saving to a .html file? :)

Comment: i suggest encoding to base 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how `save_html()` works but this is what i use on my flask website.

This solution works if you do not need to save the image.

```
import base64
import io


pngImage = io.BytesIO()
FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(pngImage) #fig is my matPlotlib instance of Figure()

# Encode PNG image to base64 string
image = "data:image/png;base64,"
image += base64.b64encode(pngImage.getvalue()).decode('utf8')
```

then in html use:

```
<img src="{{image}}">
```

Comment: Can you send me your imports? I am having problem using '.print_png'

Comment: ```  from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas```
```from matplotlib.figure import Figure```       ```import base64```
```import io```

Comment: Now my image shows a broken icon. Any thoughts? haha

Comment: I would addthis line: ```print(base64.b64encode(pngImage.getvalue()).decode('utf8'))``` then go paste the base64 from the console (it is normal that it is very long) in this website: https://base64-to-image.com/

Comment: If everything works you should see your image.

Comment: In the end I've used Plotly to render the graph :D. Anyway, thanks for your help :)))